# Is there a way to uniquely identify an instance of an LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, iframe

I have an LWC that invokes an iframe with a query parameter.  The query parameter is an external unique id outside of Salesforce.  I am attempting to associate the external unique id with an instance of the LWC.  The aim being when a user navigates to the page each LWC instance will be able to load unique content based on the associated external id, which would be stored as a custom object.

From what I've read I don't think it's possible but I'm new to this so wondering if I'm missing something or if there is anyway to synchronize loading of these instances.

I have created a custom object and can create a record which I hoped could store the external id and the LWC id.

Comment: Would you not have the unique ID as a target property for your LWC, so the admin setting up the flexipage (or other usage of the LWC) simply sets the property with the required unique ID?

Comment: The ideal is that the end user can input an external id and change it if they choose to load different content, so would prefer not to have to do this as an admin task,  However it might be the only option.